# HTML layout extra spacing due to relative positioning

Tags: php, css, html, position

I have uploaded an image on the following link which shows the layout of my html page. But I should stick to the following progress for making that layout(i.e. the fix ordering due to some restrictions and time problem).

http://tinyurl.com/9rs9m5y

The problem is the extra whitespace present below the content, which is arrived there due to the relative positioning(and yes I can't use absolute positioning too). Is there any way to remove that whitespace?

Comment: It would help if you would post a link to the full HTML, not just an image.

Comment: You can see the green whitespace below content...  http://mietabhishek.redirectme.net/coaster/CoasterInsider/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for `position:relative` in this layout. You should be using FLOATS. Your SEARCH should be part of the HEADER and not hacked-into position using relative positioning. The same goes for your right navigation.

You seriously need to re-think your entire HTML structure.

Comment: Yes I will prefer that, bt the pages are dynamically generated using php so is there any solution for this scenario?

Comment: Start with a mock-up in plain HTML, then implement THAT into your PHP.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct, but if here is any way for now?

Comment: Your layout is unstable. Changes in the sizes of elements due to different content will likely break it. You'd be wise to start over.